# Jquery array key value by index

Tags: jquery, arrays, key, associative-array

I try to get keys and values from an array.
But I really don't understand how to get the value/key for an index...

Here my script (I push keys and values in a loop then I try to get a value corresponding to a position in the array):

```
var imgArr = [];
imgArr.push({"src":$(this).find('.lightbox').data('img-src'),"title":$(this).find('.lightbox').data('img-title')});

var index = 3;
$(LbImage).attr('src', imgArr[index].src);
```

with console.log(imgArr) I get:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
src: "http://ddd/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/12/stray-cat.jpg"
title: "stray cat"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
src: "http://ddd/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/12/Birds.jpg"
title: "Birds"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
length: 9
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: the code looks fine except that your `imgArr` should have more elements (you said you used a loop to fill its items).

Comment: Yes it's in a loop. When I try to retrieve the value or the key I've got [object Object]

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to get? imgArr[index].src will of course get you whatever is stored in the data in your lightbox. So if you have an object in data, then you'll get [object Object] meaning that you are getting back the entire object, not just a single value

Comment: maybe the `.data()` returns an object, if you want to get the string, try appending `.toString()`

Comment: In fact I want to store image src and title in an array (with an each function for every image in the page). Then to get the right src and title of the image when I go to the next and prev image. I success to do it with one dimension array but I don't understand how to store and get a pair of value [{src1,img1},{src2,img2},{src3,img3}]...

Comment: OK, so where is the data you are trying to store? Is it in an attribute of the ".lightbox" element called "img-src"? I'm just struggling to see where the data is you want to store in src

Comment: Yes the data are store in data html attribute and are correctly store in my array. But I can't retrieve it by index... I've got exactly the same structure as this example in my console.log http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5B6RM/

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log( imgArr );`?

Comment: OK just saw the JSFiddle...

Comment: Would you mind posting the corresponding html as well?

Comment: I think we're heading somewhere now. In the loop can you also output a sample `console.log( $(this).find('.lightbox').data('img-src') );`?

Comment: it output the image url: http://ddd/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/12/stray-cat.jpg

Comment: Your code and you imgArr look fine. What exactly is not working as it should?

Comment: it output [object Object] when I try to retieve a key or a value

Comment: Yes this code should work just fine. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/V3uLC/